# How do I make the checker pieces in a checkerboard program move diagonally?

Tags: java

Be able to move one space diagonally or skip a space and move two spaces? 
I programmed the checkerboard in the square class, for example:

```
title = new Square(); 
tile.moveHorizontal(240);
tile.moveVertical(280);
tile.changeSize(40);
tile.changeColor("red");
tile.makeVisible();
```

and the pieces from the circle class:

```
piece = new Circle();
```

etc...

Now how do I make these pieces move diagonally?

Comment: Do you mean you want to _animate_ the diagonal motion, or just remove the piece from one location and have it appear at a diagonally adjacent square?  Also, if you're in a class, you should be asking the teacher for help first.  You might want to take a look at the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: I'm not sure what being in a class of all girls has to do with anything

Comment: Presumably moving 10 Horizontally, and 10 Vertically is the same as moving sqrt(200) diagonally.

Comment: JimGarrison the latter...